# Decompose a massive four vector in to two massless ones

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, linear-algebra, lorentz-symmetry

I'm trying to decompose a massive four-vector, $p_1$ with $p_1^2=m^2\neq0$, in to two massless ones, $k_i$ with $k_i^2=0$.  But I'm having trouble find basis vectors $k_i$ such that I can always decompose the massive vector in to a linear sum:
    $p_1 = \alpha_1 k_1 + \alpha_2 k_2$
Is there a general method for doing this or is there some physical reason why such a decomposition is not valid?
Cheers
Jack

edit:
I suppose an equivalent question would be:  Does there exist a basis set of null vectors for 4D Minkowski space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case that $p$ is space-like. Then, there is a frame in which $p = (0,\sqrt{p^2},0,0)$. Now, define $p_+ = (\sqrt{p^2},\sqrt{p^2/2},0,\sqrt{p^2/2})$ and $p_- = (-\sqrt{p^2},\sqrt{p^2/2},0,-\sqrt{p^2/2})$. Obviously, $p_\pm$ are light-like and $p = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(p_+ + p_-)$.

Proceed analogously for the time-like case.

Comment: So given any 4-vector (not necessarily in the frame in which the $E, x, z$ components are zero) I can boost it to that frame, construct $p_+$, $p_-$ and then apply the inverse boost?

Comment: @JackMedley: Yes, since the Lorentz transformations leave the scalar product of vectors unchanged (they are *isometries*), that is the general idea. (Note there might be more than a boost necessary - boosts are only a subgroup of the Lorentz trafos, rotations and combinations may also occur, but the *specific transformation* is not relevant here, only that it exists)

Comment: Ok I understand.  Though can I ask why you have choosen to have a nonzero $z$ component in the $p_\pm$ vectors?

Comment: @JackMedley: Could as well be a non-zero $y$ component. Or come to think of it, you could also just zero out both $y$ and $z$ and put $\sqrt{p^2}$ in the $x$-component. It doesn't matter, really, I don't know why I chose these two particular vectors.

Comment: I also notice that if we look $p^2=(0, m, 0, 0)^2 = -m^2$ instead of $+m^2$ and as you mentioned above the Lorentz boost doesnt change $p^2$ so is it ever possible to boost a general vector to this?

Comment: Actually I think p = (m, 0, 0, 0) would work

Comment: @JackMedley: I'm not fully sure what you're asking, but: Any *space-like* vector may be Lorentz-transformed into $(0,\sqrt{p^2},0,0)$, and any *time-like* vector may be Lorentz-tranformed into $(\sqrt{p^2},0,0,0)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19394/discussion-between-jack-medley-and-acuriousmind).